# How to get something from a webpage with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-requests

This page has a url `https://www.example.com`

```html
<html>
<body>
<button id="button1" onclick=func1()>
<button id="button2" onclick=func2()>
</body>
<script>
function func1(){
  open("/doubt?s=AAAB_BCCCDD");
}

function func2(){
  open("/doubt?s=AABB_CCDDEE");
}
//something like that, it is working ....
</script>
</html>
```

**AAAB_BCCCDD** and **AABB_CCDDEE** - both are the tokens ...

i want to get the first token in the page with python
my python code -

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
s = r.text

if "/doubt?s=" in s:
# After this i can' understand anything ...
# i want to get the first token here as a variable
```

please help me ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, after fetching the website's raw text content, you would parse the HTML first using a library like [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/). It will create a document object model (DOM) tree, which you then can query for the elements you need.

However, this won't read nor interpret JavaScript code. For your problem, you can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to extract the necessary information from the raw text.

Example:

```
import re
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
s = r.text

pattern = re.compile('/doubt\\?s=(?P<token>\\w+)')
matches = pattern.findall(s)
if len(matches) > 0:
  print(matches[0])
```